# pycharm variable and comment color

Tags: python, variables, comments, pycharm

For some reason when I declare a variable within a function using PyCharm, the font color is the same as if it were a comment (See picture). Anyone else having this problem? I didn't change any setting it just started happening, very frustrating!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can go to settings > editor > color scheme > custom and change the color for Line Comment

Same way settings > editor > color scheme > Python and change the color for variable

Answer (score 1):

That usually happens when you have not interacted with the variable anywhere else in the function.

For example, if you added a line after such as:

```
print x
```

the color would change back.

Comment: Kind of annoying if it's the first instance of your variable, wouldn't you say?

Comment: I think it's more of an indicator that the variable was defined but then never used. It has helped me identify typos in variable names later in the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to x is not used by any other function or code. If you hover your cursor over it for few second, the warning would tell you what's the reason.